# Read local SVN repository in PHP

Tags: php, svn

I have a subversion repository under /var/svn/
I am trying to use subversion to get details of the latest revision, I have tried using shell_exec to run svn info on the external address, but I couldn't get any input from it. Is there any way I can read the information from the repository itself?

**Solved:**
Decided to go with the SVN PECL modudle [see here](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php)

Comment: Do you require any kind of build functionality or is this just to get info about the repository? If not, my suggestion for using websvn seems like the answer to your question. If you do need this, please specify in an update to your question to state your desired use for accessing the SVN repository details. - liam

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[PHP has native support for SVN](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php)
<sup>(PECL though and not available on Windows)</sup>

You can also use the [Arbit](http://arbitracker.org/news.html)'s [VCS Abstraction Layer](http://arbitracker.org/vcs_wrapper.html)
<sup>(supports SVN, CVS, GIT, Mercurial and Archive)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into PHP's SVN extension?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php

Answer (score 2):

Resist the urge to write this yourself and go with a nicely constructed and maintained package like [websvn](http://www.websvn.info/) that shows you all your repositories via a web interface, including full revision history on each file and directory within the repository. [See a demo here](http://demo.websvn.info/listing.php)

This will give you all the info on the history of the repository and should best answer your question.

Comment: +1 for websvn, great package, but are you (the OP) requiring this bit of functionality to build into your own app? if so, then as others have said, PHP has a native extension for svn support; albeit experimental.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a PHP svn library. I found this on google:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4270-PHP-Retrieve-files-from-an-SVN-repository-in-pure-PHP.html

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I'm using svn log and svn cat in PHP without any problems (except for a charset issue). I basically wrap the command in shell_exec.

HTH.